# Quelle est la différence entre les expressions "Pas du tout envie" et "Pas tellement envie"?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

Pouvez-vous s'il vous plaît me donner qu'elle est la différence entre les deux expressions suivantes:

1. Pas du tout envie
2. Pas tellement envie

Je me demande aussi quelle expression peut remplacer "pas tellement" pour que je puisse montrer la différence avec "pas du tout".

Answer (score 3):

Pas du tout envie :

> - Je n'en ai vraiment pas envie (*ne ... vraiment pas*, affirmation de la négation : je dis non à cette envie),
> - Je n'en ai aucune envie.

Pas tellement envie :

> - J'en ai peu envie,
> - Je n'en ai pas vraiment envie (*ne ... pas vraiment*, le *vraiment* placé après le *pas* apporte une nuance relative à la négation : il n'est pas vrai que j'en ai [très] envie, mais j'ai pu en avoir envie précédemment)
> - J'en ai faiblement envie.

- Fort : J'en ai *très* envie.
- Normal : J'en ai envie.
- Moyen (vers l'acceptation) : J'en ai *un peu* envie
- Faible (vers le refus) : Je n'en ai *pas tellement* envie.
- Nul ou inexistant : je n'en ai *pas* envie.
- Rejet : Je n'en ai *pas du tout envie*.

Comment: Dans la classification, *pas du tout envie* est plus fort que *pas envie* : si je n'ai *pas du tout envie* de faire quelque chose, je vais mettre de l'énergie pour y échapper.

Comment: @PierreArnaud J'ai complété ma réponse avec votre suggestion

Comment: Merci, mais j'ai un autre souci! j'ai utilisé l'échelle suivante: pas du tout envie-pas tellement envie-très envie et un peu envie. Dans ce cas là quelle est la différence entre pas tellement envie et un peu envie!

Comment: @houneida J'ai positionné *un peu envie* dans l'échelle du 'désir'